# Why is my Onload event handler being called multiple times when injecting code into the browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, browser, event-handling, onload

I'm using the Chrome Extension `Custom JavaScript for Websites 2` to inject some simple JavaScript into each webpage I visit. I want to be able to run some code one time when the page is done loading. I've been using `window.onload = myFunction` however looking at the console output, I noticed that my function is being called multiple times. Depending on the webpage, my function is being called anywhere from 2 to 6 times. I have no clue why this would be happening. Even if my code was executing multiple times, it should just be resetting the onLoad handler, not actually calling my function right?

Current code that I'm injecting:

```
function ready(){
  console.log('page loaded');
}
window.onload = ready;
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint on your `console.log` call and observe the call stack in developer tools. This may give you a clue as to where the calls are coming from.

Comment: Using the `onload` might cause other trouble as well. You might be overwriting existing functions set to `window.onload`, or others might overwrite yours. I don't know about Custom JavaScript for Websites 2, but if you use the more commonly used Tampermonkey, you can use [`@run-at`](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#_run_at) to indicate when the script should be ran. (Which probably would fix the issue as well.)

Comment: You must be using `all_frames` parameter in manifest.json which runs your content script in each iframe.

Answer (score 1):

wOxxOm gave me the correct answer in the comments.

"You must be using all_frames parameter in manifest.json which runs your content script in each iframe."

After creating my own extension to inject code, I no longer had this issue.